# Should I require all .JS files using now requireJS with angularJS

Tags: angularjs

Introducing requireJS into my angjlarJS app I asked myself what happens with the bower scripts and my application scripts(services etc...).

Do I have to remove all and configure every angular bower component and application scripts with requireJs config?

```
<!-- build:js scripts/vendor.js -->
    <!-- bower:js -->
    <script src="bower_components/jquery/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/sass-bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-resource/angular-resource.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-cookies/angular-cookies.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-sanitize/angular-sanitize.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls.js"></script>
    <!-- endbower -->
    <!-- endbuild -->

        <!-- build:js({.tmp,app}) scripts/scripts.js -->
        <script src="scripts/app.js"></script>
        <script src="scripts/controllers/main.js"></script>
        <script src="scripts/services/authenticationService.js"></script>
        <!-- endbuild -->

        <script src="scripts/vendor/linq.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Due to how Angular.js loads dependencies that's not the greatest idea. Forcing the entire thing through RequireJS would mean a decent amount of Angular finicking, which isn't fun.

I would recommend instead to make sure all of those are minified (they don't look minified from the quote) and concatenate them all, then serve that big file.

Comment: What is angular finicking? And about your big file. This could be done server side minify the scripts.

Comment: Finicking with how Angular does dependencies, you would need to change how Angular does dep injection in order to get RequireJS to work meaningfully.